# How to detect if a tumblr user is logged in?

Tags: javascript, authentication, tumblr

I'm writing a theme and wanted to display content only to the admin of the blog, but I don't know how to detect if the admin is logged in.

I did notice that at the bottom of the HTML, right before the closing body tag there is this code:

```
<iframe src="http://assets.tumblr.com/iframe.html?10&src=http%3A%2F%2Fstaff.tumblr.com%2F&amp;lang=en_US&amp;name=staff" scrolling="no" width="330" height="25" frameborder="0" style="position:absolute; z-index:1337; top:0px; right:0px; border:0px; background-color:transparent; overflow:hidden;" id="tumblr_controls"></iframe>
<!--[if IE]>
<script type="text/javascript">document.getElementById('tumblr_controls').allowTransparency=true;</script>
<![endif]-->
<script type="text/javascript">_qoptions={qacct:"p-19UtqE8ngoZbM"};</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://edge.quantserve.com/quant.js"></script>     
<noscript><img src="http://pixel.quantserve.com/pixel/p-19UtqE8ngoZbM.gif" style="display:none; border-width:0px; height:1px; width:1px;" alt=""/></noscript>
```

The URL in the `iframe` (http://assets.tumblr.com/iframe.html?10&src=http%3A%2F%2Fstaff.tumblr.com%2F&lang=en_US&name=staff) leads to a page which does its own check if the user is logged in. I just haven't been able to figure out how it works.

Because this check would need to be embedded in the theme's code it must be in JavaScript.

Thanks, Spencer

Comment: What type of *content* you want to display? some helpful buttons for admin or some other stuff?

Comment: I wanted to display a menu with links to create each type of post as well as a sign out button.

Comment: I'm interested in implementation of result solution. Can you share it with me?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think problem cannot be solved because this check must be made on server, and check can't be made due to limitations of **[Tumblr Theme](http://www.tumblr.com/docs/ru/custom_themes)** engine.

**UPDATE: return to JS version**

### List of iframes:

- [Tumblr iframe for non-logged user](http://pastebin.com/KM4CV1z4)
- [Tumblr iframe for logged users [owner]](http://pastebin.com/JwgCyKvW)
- [Tumblr iframe for logged users [non-owner]](http://pastebin.com/kemFJpdD)

### Different block of code from these iframes:

#### Tumblr iframe for non-logged users:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var logged_in = (document.cookie.indexOf('logged_in=1') != -1);
</script>
…
<div style="position:absolute; top:3px; right:3px; white-space:nowrap; height:20px;">
    <span id="logged_out_controls" style="display:none;">
        <a href="https://www.tumblr.com/register" target="_top" id="follow_link">
                <img id="follow_image" alt="Follow" style="width:58px;"/>
        </a>
        <a href="https://www.tumblr.com/register/join_tumblr" target="_blank"
        id="join_link">
                <img id="join_image" alt="Join Tumblr" style="width:105px;"/>
        </a>
    </span>
</div>
```

#### Tumblr iframe for logged users [owner]:

```
<div style="position:absolute; top:3px; right:3px; white-space:nowrap; height:20px;">
    <a target="_top" href="http://www.tumblr.com/customize?redirect_to=http%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2F">
        <img src="http://assets.tumblr.com/images/iframe_customize_alpha.png?1016" alt="Customize" style="height:20px;width:80px; border-width:0px; display:block; float:left; cursor:pointer;" />
    </a>
    <a target="_top" href="http://www.tumblr.com/dashboard">
        <img src="http://assets.tumblr.com/images/iframe_dashboard_alpha.png?1016" alt="Dashboard" style="height:20px; width:81px; border-width:0px; display:block; float:left; cursor:pointer;" />
    </a>
</div>
```

#### Tumblr iframe for logged users [non-owner]:

```
<div style="position:absolute; top:3px; right:3px; white-space:nowrap; height:20px;">
    <form action="/follow" method="post" style="display:block; float:left;"onsubmit="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Iframe', 'Follow', 'example-com');">
        <input type="hidden" name="form_key" value="83jbGySgEVpQGOoZALqqoSaKfjs"/>
        <input type="hidden" name="id" value="example-com"/>
        <input type="image" src="http://assets.tumblr.com/images/iframe_follow_alpha.png?1016"style="width:58px; height:20px; border-width:0px; display:block;margin-left:3px; cursor:pointer;"alt="Follow"/>
    </form>
    <a target="_top" href="http://www.tumblr.com/dashboard">
        <imgsrc="http://assets.tumblr.com/images/iframe_dashboard_alpha.png?1016" alt="Dashboard" style="height:20px; width:81px; border-width:0px; display:block; float:left; cursor:pointer;"/>
    </a>
</div>
```

### Diffs which can be detected:

#### Iframe for **non-logged** has strange script line:

- var logged_in = (document.cookie.indexOf('logged_in=1') != -1);
- There is **NO** link with `href` attribute contains 'customize' pattern (CSS way: `a[href*='customize']`);
- There is **NO** link with `href` attribute contains 'dashboard' pattern (CSS way: `a[href*='dashboard']`);

#### Iframe for **logged** users **[owner]**:

- There is link with `href` attribute contains 'dashboard' pattern (CSS way: `a[href*='dashboard']`);
- There is link with `href` attribute contains 'customize' pattern (CSS way: `a[href*='customize']`);
- There is **NO** *'follow'* form;

#### Iframe for **logged** users **[non-owner]**:

- There is link with `href` attribute contains 'dashboard' pattern (CSS way: `a[href*='dashboard']`);
- There is *'follow'* form;
- There is **NO** link with `href` attribute contains 'customize' pattern (CSS way: `a[href*='customize']`);

### Conclusion

However I find this solution quite fragile, I think it is **possible to detect** is user owner of current blog based on **diffs** listed above.

Comment: I know there is no theme variable for this check, but was looking for a manual way to possibly detect a logged in user.

Comment: @Spencer Maybe i found the way to achieve the goal

Comment: Aren't you going to violate cross-domain resitrictions if you try to examine the Iframe?

Comment: @FelixBonkoski `iframe` is on subdomain, so as far as i know there is no problem in this case.