# Skip Google Analytics on Tumblr when logged in

Tags: google-analytics, tumblr

I am integrating Google Analytics in my tumblr-Template. The Problem is, every time I visit the blog to see how it looks like, Google will count me as a visitor. I would like to avoid it.
So I need something Like this in my template:

```
{block:NotAdmin}
   <#Google-Script>
{/block:NotAdmin}
```

I couldn't find anything useful on the [tumblr-Site](http://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/custom_themes/).

Any suggestions?

ps. I am visiting the blog from different IP´s, so Google-IP-Filter wont work.

Comment: As far as I know, there is no foolproof way of implementing at this time since Tumblr does not provide such a variable/block to use in your theme code.
Well, you can check the user's cookies, which Tumblr actually does itself to check which iFrame to load, and their assets iFrame to determine what type of user they are, and then add the GA scripts to the header on an as-needed basis, but I'm not sure if that will work since you'll have to add the scripts after the page is already loaded.

Answer (score 2):

Some possible ways to detect if a user is signed in: [How to detect if a tumblr user is logged in?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11626074/how-to-detect-if-a-tumblr-user-is-logged-in)

Assuming you can get some form of the above code working, you can add a conditional to the _trackPageview call:

```
  if (!logged_in)_gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);
```

This way, all the analytics code is still being loaded, but the pageviews are not being tracked when you're logged in.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps try [Google's opt-out extension](https://tools.google.com/dlpage/gaoptout/)? A good thing to do would be to set up a new user within Google Chrome, and switch to this user whenever you want to view the blog.