# Is there anyway to know when user is logged in to tumblr via javascript?

Tags: tumblr

I am looking for ways to do this. API doesn't seem to be helping. I tried many ways without api too. I need to achieve this with javascript.

Does anyone know any kind of way to do this?

I have tried something like this:
[How to detect if a tumblr user is logged in?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11626074/how-to-detect-if-a-tumblr-user-is-logged-in)
https://github.com/apandhi/Tumblr-Logged-In-Checker

which is without api. I can't find how to do this with api and I am not sure if it's even possible.

Comment: I can't get the github code to work, I assume it may have worked at one time. I think your best bet is already in the linked answer, detect the logged_in cookie, it will have a different value for logged in and not logged in.

Answer (score 0):

To update my comment.

If you run this code on your blog (or in the console)

```
document.cookie.indexOf('logged_in=1') != -1;
```

It returns `true` if user is logged in, or `false` if user is not logged in.

By this logic you can set this equal to a variable and run different functions depending on the value of the variable.

```
var user_logged_in = document.cookie.indexOf('logged_in=1') != -1;

if(user_logged_in) {
    // insert code here for logged in users
}else{
   // insert code here for non logged in users
}
```